# Unstable mouseenter/mouseleave submenu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a submenu activated by hovering over the main menu.

It's working and I'm trying to make is work smoothly before cleaning up my code.

Problem is that it's kind of random if it's working or not. Loading the page and navigating the mouse to the hover-area works fine. But then swiping it around a bit and going back and forth fast breaks it.

So, I'm guessing it has something to do with the timeout somehow, but not sure why - might there be a better way of achieving it?

**HTML Main menu and placeholder for sub menu and JS/Jquery are as below**

```js
// Example of menu items
var menuItems1 = [
  '<li><a href="#">Undermeny1 1</a></li>',
  '<li><a href="#">Undermeny1 2</a></li>',
  '<li><a href="#">Undermeny1 3</a></li>',
  '<li><a href="#">Undermeny1 4</a></li>'
];

var inSubMenu = false;
var lastId = "";
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.subMenuHoverArea', function() {

  if ($(this).hasClass('subMenuJS')) {
    var thisid = $(this).attr('id');
  } else {
    thisid = lastId;
  }

  if (thisid != lastId && lastId != "") {
    $('#subMenuContent').empty();
    populateMenu(thisid);
  } else {

    if (!inSubMenu) {
      $('#subMenuContent').empty();
      populateMenu(thisid);
      $('.subMenuSubMenu').fadeIn('fast');
    }

  }
  lastId = thisid;
  inSubMenu = true;

});
$(document).on('mouseleave', '.subMenuHoverArea', function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (!inSubMenu) {
      $('#subMenuContent').empty();
      $('.subMenuSubMenu').fadeOut('fast');
    }
    inSubMenu = false;

  }, 350);

});

function populateMenu(menuId) {
  // Populates ul element with li from chosen array by appending it through a for loop. Not related to problem
for(var i = 0;  i < menuItems1.length; i++){
     $('#subMenuContent').append(menuItems1[i]);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a id="menu1" href="#" class="subMenuHoverArea subMenuJS">Menu 1</a></li>
  <li><a id="menu2" href="#" class="subMenuHoverArea subMenuJS">Menu 2</a></li>
  <li><a id="menu3" href="#" class="subMenuHoverArea subMenuJS">Menu 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="subMenuSubMenu">
  <div class="contentMain">
    <ul id="subMenuContent" class="subMenuHoverArea"></ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a hover menu I ever wrote. The advantage of this is that it uses a delay for the hover to work. So if you move really quick over multiple menu items you wont get a "flashing effect". You have to hover over an element for 150ms for it to work. You can adjust this value to your liking.

It looked like your fading functions seem to cause some trouble though. Therefore i created the same effect in css and used classes to toggle which made it work a lot smoother.

How this works:

- On both mouseenter and mouseleave events the current time is saved in a global variable `lastAction`.
- On both mouseenter and mouseleave events a timer will start. After `hoverdelay` in milliseconds the timer ends.
- When the timer end it will check if the time saved before is still the same as in the global variable. If an other mouseenter/mouseleave event has occurred during this time the global will have a different value. If that is the case do nothing, otherwise run the code belonging to the event.

I replaced the jQuery fade functions with a css effect. The reason for this is because the fade effect is not good for fast changes between `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()`. `AddClass()` and `removeClass()` works a lot better for this. By adding a transition effect on the opacity you get the same fadeIn/fadeOut effect.
If you want timing to be faster or slower just change the amount of seconds.

```js
var hoverdelay = 150;
var lastAction = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#wrapper').on({
    mouseenter: mouseEnterFunction,
    mouseleave: mouseLeaveFunction
  }, '.subMenuHoverArea');
});

function mouseEnterFunction() {
  var now = (new Date().getTime());
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  lastAction = now;
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    if (lastAction === now) {
      showMenu(id);
    }
  }, hoverdelay);
}

function mouseLeaveFunction() {
  var now = (new Date().getTime());
  lastAction = now;
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    if (lastAction === now) {
      hideMenu();
    }
  }, hoverdelay);
}

function showMenu(id) {
  $('#subMenuContent').empty().append('<li>'+ id + '</li>').addClass('activeMenu');
}

function hideMenu() {
  $('#subMenuContent').removeClass('activeMenu');
}
```

```css
.subMenuJS {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#subMenuContent {
  background-color: pink;
}

.menu {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.activeMenu {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='wrapper'>
  <ul>
    <li><a id="menu1" href="#" class="subMenuHoverArea subMenuJS">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a id="menu2" href="#" class="subMenuHoverArea subMenuJS">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a id="menu3" href="#" class="subMenuHoverArea subMenuJS">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="subMenuSubMenu">
    <div class="contentMain">
      <ul id="subMenuContent" class="subMenuHoverArea menu">test</ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To answer your question about how efficient it is to create a date object every time. Here is a piece of code that does it 10000 times.

For me it will cost 10 till 20 ms to do it that often. I think that in worse case scenario that event happens 100 times in a second at max if the user is really spastic. Therefore I don't think performance is an issue. Never had complains about it on my site too.

```js
var start = (new Date().getTime());

for(var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
  var dummy = (new Date().getTime());
}

var end = (new Date().getTime());

console.log((end - start) + ' ms');
```

Comment: Looks promising in the runnable snippet! I'll try to implement it and come back to you.

Comment: It's working, but when applying the li elements to the submenu it breaks. Opening ok, but moving the mouse to the li elements _within_ the #subMenuContent area closes the menu. Logged the mouseenter event and it is triggered when moving to the li, but still closes.

Comment: @Zony86 Hard to understand what you mean without seeing the code. Can you update your snippet with the result you have now?

Comment: Sorry, got caught up in something else at work. Continuing tomorrow

Comment: Np, I got an idea where the problem is. I changed to code to event delegation. That might solve your issue already. If not i need to see your code. Note: I made a wrapper div that does the event delegation.

Comment: It was my css that messed it up. Some hidden absolute elements not related to this exact menu. Accepted your answer. Working nicely :) One question though : creating a Date object on every mouseenter/leave - isn't it unnecessary expensive? Or is it so minimal that it isn't cared about?

Comment: @Zony86 I think you shouldn't worry about it. I made a (simple) test how long it takes to do it 10000 times. Probably not the best performance testing code but you will get the idea that it's not so expensive.

Comment: Great. One last question. As I'm adding li elements to the DOM when doing the mouseenter : "$('#wrapper').on({mouseenter: function() {" will not trigger on the added elements. Im trying to modify the code to use $(document).... instead, but can't seem to get it working correctly.

Comment: Note the last parameter of the on function `'.subMenuHoverArea'`. You will need that to make the events delegated. Don't do it on `document` but get the closest possible parent that is static (element that is on the page when the page is loaded). Putting it on the document makes it's cost more computing power. For testing purposes you can do that though.

Comment: @Zony86 I edited my answer so the event handlers are normal functions. This might make the code more readable and understandable for you.

Comment: Thanks. It was not related to what I though so i'll keep your first example as it looks more neat. The problem-maker is this : When changing the menu I need to empty it first (as I am appending new li elements). The empty() before the append is what kills the code. If I remove empty() and just appends a never-ending row of li elements it's working fine, but as soon as I clean it first it breaks (mouseleave is triggered when hovering over li). Ref : $('#subMenuContent').empty();

Comment: @Zony86 I updated my snippet with the `empty()` function and `append()` but it seems to work fine in my snippet. I suggest to open a new question with a snippet that reproduces this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use jquery "hover" method.

Try this :

```js
var menuItems1 = [
    '<li><a href="#">Undermeny1 1</a></li>',
    '<li><a href="#">Undermeny1 2</a></li>',
    '<li><a href="#">Undermeny1 3</a></li>',
    '<li><a href="#">Undermeny1 4</a></li>'
];

var inSubMenu = false;
var lastId = "";

$(document).ready(function(){



$('.subMenuHoverArea').hover(function() {
 var thisid=''
 console.log('mouse enter');
    if ($(this).hasClass('subMenuJS')) {
        thisid = $(this).attr('id');
    } else {
        thisid = lastId;
    }

    if (thisid != lastId && lastId != "") {
        $('#subMenuContent').html('');
        populateMenu(thisid);
  $('.subMenuSubMenu').fadeIn('fast');
    } else {

        if (!inSubMenu) {
            $('#subMenuContent').html('');
            populateMenu(thisid);
            $('.subMenuSubMenu').fadeIn('fast');
        }

    }
    lastId = thisid;
    inSubMenu = true;

}, function() {

console.log('mouse leave');
    setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('time out, and inSubMenu = ' + inSubMenu);
        if (!inSubMenu) {
            $('#subMenuContent').html('');
            $('.subMenuSubMenu').fadeOut('fast');
        }
        inSubMenu = false;
    }, 350);
});

});//jq
function populateMenu(menuId){
 $('<li> Mouse Moved on : ' + menuId + '</li>').appendTo($('#subMenuContent'));
   // Populates ul element with li from chosen array by appending it through a for loop. Not related to problem
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="parentMenu">
     <li><a id="menu1" href="#" class="subMenuHoverArea subMenuJS">Menu 1</a></li>
     <li><a id="menu2" href="#" class="subMenuHoverArea subMenuJS">Menu 2</a></li>
     <li><a id="menu3" href="#" class="subMenuHoverArea subMenuJS">Menu 3</a></li>
 </ul>
<div class="subMenuSubMenu">
    <div class="contentMain">
        <ul id="subMenuContent" class="subMenuHoverArea"></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Same result. Still the same problem. It's happening with your runnable code snippet as well if messing around with the mouse a bit.

Comment: Have you tried applying `.stop(true)` before your fade animations? e.g `$('.subMenuSubMenu').stop(true).fadeOut('fast');` @Zony86

Comment: @SeanT I tried it now. Same problem. It's 90% satisfying (it was with my original code as well) - but fast sudden movements of the mouse can still make problem where the menu doesn't open when the mouse is above the hover/mouseenter areas.

Comment: @Zony86 `mouseleave` events are not 100% reliable, you would do better to find yourself a css solution.