# mouseenter and mouseleave problems with dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu, menu

I need to make dropdown menu. Problem is that HTML structure is forcing me to use jQuery not CSS with fadeIN and fadeOut options. In main Menu I got options like Blog Category and About me. Problem is submenu is added later on by somone and i cant change it (since I cant change html). I need to make submenu to show ONLY when i hover on Category but when i use mouseenter and mouseleave on Category ofc it will vanish beofre I manage to click sth in submenu. How to make condition (probably some if?) to make submenu stay on site when mouse is movedout from Category but still sits on div with submenu?

```
subMenu: function () {
        //
        console.log('subMenu')  
        //
        $("#mainNav > ul > li:nth-child(2)").mouseenter(function(){
            $(".category-menu").fadeIn();

        })

        $("#mainNav > ul > li:nth-child(2)").mouseleave(function(){
            $(".category-menu").fadeOut();

        })
    },
```

this is my code it sucks I know but I tried several solutions and I cant figure it out. Can somone help me with adjusting my code?

Basicaly my problem is that submenu is not a part of main nav and I am forbidden to change it in html.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unstable mouseenter/mouseleave submenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51856625/unstable-mouseenter-mouseleave-submenu)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `$(".category-menu")` is your submenu item you can use the answer to this question: [mouseenter mouseleave submenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51856625/unstable-mouseenter-mouseleave-submenu) you can also use `.css()` for setting simple CSS on elements dynamically with jQuery take a look at the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/css/).